# Highlight strings that match a search term

Tags: performance, react.js, jsx

I'm writing a ctrl+f function so to speak in React that allows a user to search for a term in a list of words, and if the term matches any of the words in the list then it highlights it. To do this, I'm currently using `document.querySelectorAll` to retrieve all of the words in the list and manipulate them (highlight) if there is a match. Because this is React I feel very bad about using the querySelector to grab the words and feel I should be using refs perhaps, but not sure how comparable that is or if that works in this particular scenario. Here is my code:

```
const HighlightSearchTerm = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const regex = new RegExp(searchTerm, "gi");
    const labels = document.querySelectorAll(".label"); // use refs??

    labels.forEach(label => {
      label.innerHTML = label.innerText.replace(regex, match =>
        `<span class="highlight">${match}</span>`
      );
    });
  }, [searchTerm]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        type="text"
        value={searchTerm}
        placeholder="Search Labels"
        onChange={event => setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can see, implementing it this way has to also call `document.querySelectorAll` each time the user types a letter or makes a change which isn't very efficient and is causing `[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took <N>ms` to appear in the console many times when working with large lists. Instead, I would like to

1. Not use `document.querySelectorAll` to retrieve the words in the list (use refs if possible?)
2. Not fetch the list of words each time I type due to the fact the list won't change once the component is rendered (possibly render them when the component mounts, although it seems I can't do this currently when using querySelector)

Any other optimization suggestions would also be very much appreciated.

Current working example: https://codepen.io/andrewgarrison/pen/eYOWjZB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than extract the Search input in to a different component I would suggest you keep the input and list in the same component.

This way when printing the list you can highlight the search term directly.

```
const HighlightableList = (props) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
  const regex = new RegExp(searchTerm, "gi");

  const items = props.terms.map((term, index) => (
      <div
        className="label"
        key={index}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: term.replace(regex, match => `<span class="highlight">${match}</span>`)
        }}
      />
    ));

    return (
      <>
        <input 
          type="text"
          value={searchTerm}
          placeholder="Search Labels"
          onChange={event => setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}
        />
        <div className="label-container">
          {items}
        </div>
      </>
    );
}
```

https://codepen.io/rockingskier/pen/YzKrGNR

*Side notes:*

Don't make each list item a `label`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

> The HTML  element represents a caption for an item in a user interface.

That would suggest that each item in the list has its own user input.  In fact there is only one input (search) and that should really have a label of its own.  I'll let you implement that.

Additionally due the the "list-iness" of the data I have converted it to a `ul` with each item as an `li`.